# What's the general idea (intuition) behind Andrej's topos where reals are countable?

Tags: mathematics, applications, theorems-announced-on-april-first

I am very surprised that Andrej Bauer [claimed](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1509794127898374149) to have found a topos where reals are countable. He said it'll take a month to write down the proof, and I think that's very understandable.

However, I'm very curious about the general idea behind that -- I have just learned some classical proofs that reals are uncountable, and I can make sense of those proofs. What kind of topos will make reals countable?

Comment: I would check the date ;)

Comment: This is a theorem for reals!

Comment: ... and as a matter of fact, I've already produced a proof of this using the [Falso proof assistant](https://inutile.club/estatis/falso/).

Comment: This is getting out of hand.

Comment: What should I do to this question? Delete it?

Comment: You never should have asked it. What I really wonder is if a moderator is asked to migrate this to MathOverflow if they would?

Comment: There's no need to create even more confusion.

Comment: We should upvote it and then close the question --- this avoids confusion *and* won't have the Community bot delete it :P

Comment: IIRC there are nontrivial foundations https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410703/subcountability/410755#410755 such as CZF + ESC (every set is subcountable) where all sets are subcountable (there exists a surjection from the natural numbers to them.) Not sure if that forms a topos though. Anyhow I think the tricky part is an injection from the reals to the naturals? OFC this is a joke I think.

Comment: in what way is this question opinionated?

Comment: The April Fool's joke is now complete: https://researchseminars.org/talk/ToposInstituteColloquium/57/ (but this question is still off-topic for this site).